# Code Golf - Generate nearby page numbers based on the current page

Tags: algorithm, code-golf, rosetta-stone

The challenge is to create an algorithm for generating a specifically-sized subset of numbers in a sequence based on the current position in that sequence.

While navigating through the many pages of content on a busy site like Stack Overflow or Digg it is often desirable to give the user a way to quickly jump to the first page, the last page or a specific page which is *near* the current page they are viewing.

### Requirements

- First and last page numbers are *always* displayed
- The subset of page numbers will
  contain the current page number
  as well as page numbers before and/or
  after it (depending on current page)
- The subset of page numbers will
  always be a fixed number of pages and
  can never exceed or fall short of
  that fixed number unless:

  - `totalPages
    < fixedWidth`
- The position of the current page
  number in the subset is fixed
  unless:

  - `1 <= currentPage <
    (fixedWidth - defaultPostion)`
    or
  - `(totalPages -
    currentPage) < (fixedWidth - defaultPostion)`
- Output should indicate when there is a
  difference *greater than 0* between the first
  page of data and the first page of
  the subset as well as between the 
  last page of the subset and the last page 
  of data. This indicator should appear
  at most once in either position.

If you can't picture this yet, take a look at your Stack Overflow profile under questions/answers. If you have more than 10 of either one, you should see paging links at the bottom which are generated in exactly this fashion. That, or scroll to the bottom of http://digg.com and observe their paging control.

### Examples

All examples assume a subset size of 5 and the current page in position 3, but these 
should be configurable in your solution. `...` indicates the gap between page numbers, `[x]` indicates the current page.

---

Current Page: 1 of 30

Output:  `[x][2][3][4][5]...[30]`

---

Current Page: 2 of 30

Output:  `[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]`

---

Current Page: 13 of 30

Output:  `[1]...[11][12][x][14][15]...[30]`

---

Current Page: 27 of 30

Output:  `[1]...[25][26][x][28][29][30]`

---

Current Page: 30 of 30

Output:  `[1]...[26][27][28][29][x]`

---

Current Page: 3 of 6

Output:  `[1][2][x][4][5][6]`

---

Current Page: 4 of 7

Output:  `[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]`

---

### Additional Clarifications

- First and last pages do not count toward
  `numberOfPages` unless they are sequentially
  part of `numberOfPages` as in 
  `[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]` or 
  `[1]...[26][27][28][x][30]`, but not in
  `[1]...[8][9][x][11][12]...[30]`
- No gap indicator should be included if the distance
  between either end of the subset and the first
  or last page is less than 1. Thus, it is possible
  to have a non-breaking sequence of pages up to 
  `fixedWidth + 2` as in `[1][2][3][x][5][6]...[15]` or
  `[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]`

**Solutions in any and all languages are welcome.**

**Good luck!**

Comment: Figure out your own SEO code.

Comment: What does pagination have to do with SEO in this example?

Comment: @Yuriy for the record, I had to solve this yesterday; which I did.

Comment: @AvatarKava: I helped to do somewhat the same thing for SEO. The idea, although I'm not 100% sure, was to have an exact number of links on the page.

Comment: Should page 2 of 30 be `[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]` or `[1][x][3][4]...[30]`? You didn't make it very clear.

Comment: @rlbond How should I clarify the original question to make it clearer? It would be `[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]`. There will always be *at least* 4 links surrounding the current page (if possible).

Comment: And what about the case when i'm on page 1 of 20 for example?

Comment: I think that your (27 30) example is not right.

Comment: @Peterk `[1][2][3][4][5]...[20]`.

Comment: @Svante you're right. I just fixed it.

Comment: @Nathan why not `[x][2][3][4][5]...[20]` ?

Comment: @seanizer Because I typed it wrong. :)

Comment: I don't get how a width of 5 pages can result in 1-5 + 30? surely that's 6 pages? or does the width only count for the ones surrounding the current page? Since you're saying the only case where there are less than width pages shown is when numberOfPages < fixedWidth, if you're not counting first and last, that would be when numberOfPages < (fixedWidth + 2). There's inconsistencies in your spec here.

Comment: @Lasse Your assessment is accurate and my wording is a little a funky, I agree. First and last pages do not count toward the fixed numberOfPages unless they are sequentially part of numberOfPages- as in `[1][x][3][4][5]..[30]`.

Comment: What if there's 7 pages, and you're on page 4? `[1]...[2][3][x][5][6]...[7]`?

Comment: @Lasse Please see the second bullet under Additional Clarifications. `[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]`

Answer (score 7):

### Python - <strike>156</strike> <del>182</del> 140 characters

```
f=lambda c,m,n:'...'.join(''.join((' ','[%s]'%(p,'x')[p==c])[min(m-n,c-1-n/2)<p<max(n+1,c+1+n/2)or p in(1,m)]for p in range(1,m+1)).split())
```

And testing against examples in OP:

```
for c, m, expect in (
    (1,  30, "[x][2][3][4][5]...[30]"),
    (2,  30, "[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]"),
    (13, 30, "[1]...[11][12][x][14][15]...[30]"),
    (27, 30, "[1]...[25][26][x][28][29][30]"),
    (30, 30, "[1]...[26][27][28][29][x]"),
    (3,  6,  "[1][2][x][4][5][6]"),
    (4,  7,  "[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]"),
):
    output = f(c, m, 5)
    print "%3d %3d %-40s : %s" % (c, m, output, output == expect)
```

Thanks for the comments. :)

PS. heavily edited to decrease char count and to add `n`=number of pages around the current one (`m` is max number of pages and `c` is the current page no)

Comment: I think that the output is not correct in the (2 30) case.  Also, subset size and the position of the current page in the subset are not configurable.

Comment: 2 of 30 should be `[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]`

Comment: that would be 6 pages, would it not?, 1, x, 3, 4, 5 and 30

Comment: The examples in the question make it clear that there should always be 5 surrounding pages, plus the end points if not already shown.

Comment: Aggresively edited to decrease char count and to add n=number of pages around the current one

Answer (score 4):

## GolfScript - <s>89</s> <s>80</s> 78 chars

```
~:&;\:C;:T,{-1%[T&-T)C-:C&2/-(]$0=:|1>{.1<\|>}*}2*]${{)]`[C]`/'[x]'*}%}%'...'*
```

Sample I/O:

```
$ echo "27 30 5"|golfscript page_numbers.gs
[1]...[25][26][x][28][29][30]
```

Output for all page numbers takes 83 chars (minor modifications to the main body).

```
~:&;:T,{:C;T,{-1%[T&-T(C-:C&2/-]$0=:|1>{.1<\|>}*}2*]${{)]`[C)]`/'[x]'*}%}%'...'*n}
```

Sample I/O:

```
$ echo "7 5"|golfscript page_numbers.gs
[x][2][3][4][5]...[7]
[1][x][3][4][5]...[7]
[1][2][x][4][5]...[7]
[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]
[1]...[3][4][x][6][7]
[1]...[3][4][5][x][7]
[1]...[3][4][5][6][x]

$ echo "7 3"|golfscript page_numbers.gs
[x][2][3]...[7]
[1][x][3]...[7]
[1][2][x][4]...[7]
[1]...[3][x][5]...[7]
[1]...[4][x][6][7]
[1]...[5][x][7]
[1]...[5][6][x]
```

Answer (score 3):

### **F# !** - 233 significant characters.

All options supported and within specs.

Program:

```
let P c b n f m s =
    let p = b/2
    let u = max 1 (if n-b <= c-p   then n-b+1 else max 1 (c-p))
    let v = min n (if b   >= c+p-1 then b     else min n (c+p))
    let P = printf
    let C c a n = if c then P a n
    C (u > 1)  f   1
    C (u = 3)  f   2
    C (u > 3) "%s" s
    let I = Seq.iter (P f)
    I {u .. c-1}
    P "%s" m
    I {c+1 .. v}
    C (n - 2 > v) "%s" s
    C (v = n - 2)  f   (n-1)
    C (n > v)      f   n
```

Test:

```
for p in 1..6 do
    P p 5 30 "[%d]" "[x]" "..."
    printfn ""

for p in 25..30 do
    P p 5 30 "[%d]" "[x]" "..."
    printfn ""
```

Output:

```
[x][2][3][4][5]...[30]
[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]
[1][2][x][4][5]...[30]
[1][2][3][x][5]...[30]
[1][2][3][4][x][6][7]...[30]
[1]...[4][5][x][7][8]...[30]

[1]...[23][24][x][26][27]...[30]
[1]...[24][25][x][27][28][29][30]
[1]...[26][x][28][29][30]
[1]...[26][27][x][29][30]
[1]...[26][27][28][x][30]
[1]...[26][27][28][29][x]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Common Lisp: 262 significant characters

> (defun [(n)(format t"[~a]"n))(defun p(c m &key(s 5)(p 2))(let((l(max(min(- c p)(- m s -1))1))(r(min(max(+ c(- p)s -1)s)m)))(when(> l 1)([ 1))(when(> l 2)(princ"..."))(loop for n from l to r do([ (if(= n c)#\x n)))(when(< r(1- m))(princ"..."))(when(< r m)([ m))))

Uncompressed:

```
(defun print[] (n)
  (format t "[~a]" n))

(defun page-bar (current max &key (subset-size 5) (current-position 2))
  (let ((left (max (min (- current current-position)
                        (- max subset-size -1))
                   1))
        (right (min (max (+ current (- current-position) subset-size -1)
                         subset-size)
                    max)))
    (when (> left 1) (print[] 1))
    (when (> left 2) (princ "..."))
    (loop for p from left upto right
          do (print[] (if (= p current) #\x p)))
    (when (< right (1- max)) (princ "..."))
    (when (< right max) (print[] max))))
```

Testing:

```
CL-USER> (mapc (lambda (n) (p n 7) (format t "~%")) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
[x][2][3][4][5]...[7]
[1][x][3][4][5]...[7]
[1][2][x][4][5]...[7]
[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]
[1]...[3][4][x][6][7]
[1]...[3][4][5][x][7]
[1]...[3][4][5][6][x]
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
CL-USER> (p 1 1)
[x]
NIL
CL-USER> (p 1 2)
[x][2]
NIL
CL-USER> (p 0 0)
NIL
CL-USER> (p 0 1)
[1]
NIL
CL-USER> (p 0 30)
[1][2][3][4][5]...[30]
NIL
CL-USER> (p 31 30)
[1]...[26][27][28][29][30]
NIL
```

The subset size and the position of the current page in that subset can be given in optional parameters (`:current-position` is zero-based within the subset, naturally):

```
CL-USER> (page-bar 8 15 :subset-size 6 :current-position 5)
[1]...[3][4][5][6][7][x]...[15]
NIL
```

*EDIT:*  The call in the compressed version would be:

```
CL-USER> (p 8 15 :s 6 :p 5)
```

Comment: People actually use LISP? I thought that was just a fairy tale!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 234 chars

```
function pages($t,$c,$s=5){$m=ceil($s/2);$p=range(1,$t);$p[$c-1]='x';$a=array();return preg_replace('~(\[('.implode('|',array_merge($c-$m<2?$a:range(2,$c-$m),$t-1<$c+$m?$a:range($c+$m,$t-1))).')\])+~','...','['.implode('][',$p).']');}
```

(Sort of) unminified:

```
function pages($max, $current, $subset=5) {
    $m = ceil($subset / 2); // amount to go in each direction
    $arr = range(1, $max); // array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
    $arr[$current-1] = 'x'; // array(1, 2, 3, 4, x, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

    // replace ~(\[(2|8|9)\])+~ with ...
    $pattern = '~(\[(' . implode('|', array_merge($current-$m >= 2 ? range(2, $current-$m) : array(), $max-1 >= $current+$m ? range($current+$m, $max-1): array())) . ')\])+~';
    return preg_replace($pattern, '...', '['.implode('][',$arr).']');
}
```

This doesn't follow the spec exactly (`[1][x][3][4]...[30]` instead of `[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]`), but it would become a lot less elegant accounting for that.

Comment: The complication is part of the challenge.

Comment: Producing a wrong answer elegantly is still producing a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 240/<strike>195</strike> 184 chars

Similar to the other C# answer but with some nasty side-effect filled LINQ. I would imagine this could be somewhat shorter.

```
void Pages(int p,int t,int s) {
  int h=s/2,l=0;
  foreach(var c in Enumerable.Range(1,t).Where(x=>x==1||x==t||(p+h<s&&x<=s)||(p-h>t-s&&x>t-s)||(x>=p-h&&x<=p+h)).Select(x=>{Console.Write((x-l>1?"...":"")+(x==p?"[X]":"["+x+"]"));l=x;return x;}));
}
```

Edit:

Turns out the imperative version is shorter by a good margin (<strike>195</strike> 184 characters):

```
void Pages(int p,int t,int s){
  int h=s/2,l=0,i=1;
  for(;i<=t;i++)
    if(i==1||i==t||p+h<s&&i<=s||p-h>t-s&&i>t-s||i>=p-h&&i<=p+h){
      Console.Write((i-l>1?"...":"")+(i==p?"[X]":"["+i+"]"));
      l=i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can move the `i=1` from the `for` loop up to the `int` declaration; you don't need the braces in the `for` loop; and you don't need the parens around the `&&` clauses in the `if` statement. You could probably save at least 11 strokes this way.

Comment: I like, I like! Your imperative solution is a lot cleaner than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, down to 184.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 92 chars

```
$_=join'',map{$_==1||$_==$n||abs($_-$x)<=$a?$_==$x?'[x]':"[$_]":'_'}(1..$n);s/_+/.../g;print
```

Full test:

```
@i=(
 [1,30,2],
 [2,30,2],
 [13,30,2],
 [27,30,2],
 [30,30,2],
 [3,6,2],
 [4,7,2]
);

for$r(@i)
{
($x,$n,$a)=@$r;

$_=join'',map{$_==1||$_==$n||abs($_-$x)<=$a?$_==$x?'[x]':"[$_]":'_'}(1..$n);s/_+/.../g;print
;print"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python - 321 characters

I'm assuming you're typing in the current page and total pages on the command line (stdin):

```
import sys
p=sys.stdout.write
c,t=raw_input().split()
c,t=int(c),int(t)
r=range(1,t+1)
l=len(r)
p("[1]")
if c>7:
 p("...")
for n in r[c-3:c+2]:
 if n==1:continue
 if n-t==-5 and l>7:continue
 if c==n:n="X"
 p("[%s]"%n)
if l<7:
 for n in range(2,6):
  if c==n:n="X"
  p("[%s]"%n)
if r[c+2]<t and l>6:
 p("...")
p("[%d]"%t)
```

Not really golfed (just short names) so I expect the best solution to be at least half this length.

### Example

```
python pag.py
3 30
[1][2][X][4][5]...[30]
```

**Edit:** I realize this fails for thing like "2 4" or "2 2" - it assumes that are at least 6 pages. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

**Groovy: <s>242</s> 232 chars**, supports configurable group length

Call syntax: `Paging(currentOffset, totalWidth, groupSize)`

```
def(c,t,g)=args.collect{it.toInteger()};def p,s=Math.max(c-(g/2).toInteger(),1);p='['+((c==1?'x':1)+(s>2?']...':']'));(s..Math.min(s+g-1,t)).each{if(it>1&&it<t)p+='['+(c==it?'x':it)+']'};print p+(t>s+g?'...[':'[')+(t==c?'x':t)+']';
```

Readable version:

```
def (c,t,g) = args.collect{it.toInteger()};
def p,s = Math.max(c - (g/2).toInteger(), 1);
p = '['+((c==1?'x':1)+(s>2?']...':']'));
(s .. Math.min(s+g-1,t)).each{
    if(it > 1 && it < t)
        p += '[' + (c == it ? 'x' : it) + ']'
};
print p + (t > s + g ? '...[' : '[') + (t==c ? 'x' : t) + ']';
```

Calling it like this:

```
Paging ([1, 20, 5])
println '';
Paging ([10, 20, 5])
println '';
Paging ([20, 20, 5])
println '';
Paging ([7, 17, 3])
println '';
Paging ([2, 228, 3])
println '';
Paging ([2, 5, 3])
println '';
Paging ([1, 5, 5])
```

produces these results:

```
[x][2][3][4][5]...[20]
[1]...[8][9][x][11][12]...[20]
[1]...[18][19][x]
[1]...[6][x][8]...[17]
[1][x][3]...[228]
[1][x][3]...[5]
[x][2][3][4][5]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby 1.9 - 197 characters

```
p,s,t=$*.map &:to_i
a=p-s/2
e=a+s-1
a<1&&(e+=1-a;a=1)
e>t&&(a-=e-t;e=t)
s>=t&&(a=1;e=t)
m=(a..e).map{|n|"[#{n==p ??x:n}]"}.join
a>2&&m='...'+m
a>1&&m='[1]'+m
e<t-1&&m<<'...'
e<t&&m<<"[#{t}]"
puts m
```

Usage: `ruby pager.rb [position] [sampleSize] [totalWidth]`

Comment: `ruby pager.rb 1 5 7` outputs `[120][2][3][4][5]...[7]`.  I have ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-linux].

Comment: It only runs properly in Ruby 1.9, due to the character literal (`?x`) in the longest line. (It returns `120` on 1.8 and `'x'` on 1.9, hence the difference)

Answer (score 0):

## C# 278 Characters

---

### Program

```
void Pages(int c,int t,int w){
    int p=(w/2)+1;
    int b=c-p;
    int f=c+(w-p);
    if(b<0){
        f+=b*-1;
    }else if(f>t){
        b-=f-t;
        f=t;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=t;i++){
        if(t<=w||(i==1||i==t)||(i>b&&i<=f))
            Console.Write(i==c?"[X]":"[{0}]",i);
        else if(t>w&&(i==b||i==f+1))
            Console.Write("...");
    }
}
```

### Test

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    Pages(i,5,5);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

for(int i=1;i<=15;i++) {
    Pages(i,15,5);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

### Output

```
[X][2][3][4][5]
[1][X][3][4][5]
[1][2][X][4][5]
[1][2][3][X][5]
[1][2][3][4][X]

[X][2][3][4][5]...[15]
[1][X][3][4][5]...[15]
[1][2][X][4][5]...[15]
[1][2][3][X][5][6]...[15]
[1]...[3][4][X][6][7]...[15]
[1]...[4][5][X][7][8]...[15]
[1]...[5][6][X][8][9]...[15]
[1]...[6][7][X][9][10]...[15]
[1]...[7][8][X][10][11]...[15]
[1]...[8][9][X][11][12]...[15]
[1]...[9][10][X][12][13]...[15]
[1]...[10][11][X][13][14][15]
[1]...[11][12][X][14][15]
[1]...[11][12][13][X][15]
[1]...[11][12][13][14][X]
```

Comment: @Mau yes it does. Page 12 falls in position 3 in a subset of 5- `[10][11][x][13][14]` and then `[15]` follows it without breaking sequence so no `...` is required. The same 6-in-a-row situation is duplicated by page 4 of 15: `[1][2][3][x][5][6]...[15]`. Test the other C# solution and you'll see the same output.

Answer (score 0):

### Python - 334 characters - complete functionality

I realize a shorter answer has already been posted, but that one doesn't support configurable width and position in the subset of pages. Mine does.

```
def paginator(c, n, w, o):
    b = range(c-w/2+o,c+w/2+1+o)
    b = [e+abs(b[0])+1 for e in b]if b[0]<=0 else[e-abs(n-b[w-1])for e in b]if b[w-1]>n else b
    p = ([]if 1 in b else[1])+b+([]if n in b else[n])
    return ''.join(('...'if p[i]-p[i-1]!=1 and i>0 and i<len(p)else'')+'[%d]'%p[i]if p[i]!=c else'[x]'for i in range(len(p)))
```

And here are the tests that all pass

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for current, n, width, offset, expect in (
        (1,  30, 5, 0, "[x][2][3][4][5]...[30]"),
        (2,  30, 5, 0, "[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]"),
        (13, 30, 5, 0, "[1]...[11][12][x][14][15]...[30]"),
        (13, 30, 5, 1, "[1]...[12][x][14][15][16]...[30]"),
        (13, 30, 5, -1, "[1]...[10][11][12][x][14]...[30]"),
        (27, 30, 5, 0, "[1]...[25][26][x][28][29][30]"),
        (30, 30, 5, 0, "[1]...[26][27][28][29][x]"),
        (30, 30, 5, 1, "[1]...[26][27][28][29][x]"),
        (3,  6, 5, 0,  "[1][2][x][4][5][6]"),
        (3,  6, 5, -1,  "[1][2][x][4][5][6]"),
        (3,  6, 5, 1,  "[1][2][x][4][5][6]"),
        (4,  7, 5, 0,  "[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]"),
        ):
        output = paginator(current, n, width, offset)
        print "%3d %3d %3d %3d %-40s : %s" % (current, n, width, offset, output, output == expect)
        print ''
```

This is my first code-golf, awesome stuff, going to do a lot more from now on :P

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript - <strike>398</strike> 393 characters

### Working Function

`v(j, o, l)`, where:

- `j` is the page number
- `o` is the total number of pages
- `l` is the number of pages to display (subset size)

`v(10, 30, 5)` returns: `[1]...[8][9][x][11][12]…[30]`

```
function v(j,o,l){function k(q){return q.length}function y(n,m){t=[];while(n<=m){t.push(n);n++}return t}r=y(1,j-1);g=y(j+1,o);b=k(r);a=k(g);c=l/2;(b>l/2&&a>=c)?r=r.splice(-l/2):((a<=c)?r=r.splice(-l+a+1):0);b=k(r);g=g.slice(0,l-1-b);a=k(g);r.push("x");g[a-1]==o-1?g.push(o):0;r[0]==2?r.unshift(1):0;r=r.concat(g);return(r[0]>2?"[1]...":"")+"["+r.join("][")+"]"+(g[k(g)-1]<o-1?"...["+o+"]":"")}
```

---

### Uncompressed version

```
function run(cp, tp, l) {
function y(n,m){t=[];while(n<=m){t.push(n);n++}return t};
var before=y(1, cp-1);

var after=y(cp+1, tp);

var b=before.length;
var a=after.length;

var c=Math.floor(l/2);

if (b>l/2 && a>=c) {
    before=before.splice(-l/2);

} else if (a<=c) {
    before=before.splice(-(l-a)+1);
}
b=before.length;

after=after.slice(0, l-1-b);
a=after.length

before.push("x");

if (after[a-1]==tp-1)
    after.push(tp);

if (before[0]==2)
    before.unshift(1);

before=before.concat(after);

// Add bounds to either side
var pre=["",""];
if (before[0]>2) pre[0]="[1]...";
if (after[after.length-1]<tp-1) pre[1]="...["+tp+"]";

return pre[0]+"["+before.join("][")+"]"+pre[1];
}
```

### A simple test function

```
function testValues() {
var ts=[1, 30, "[x][2][3][4][5]...[30]",
        2, 30, "[1][x][3][4][5]...[30]",
        13, 30, "[1]...[11][12][x][14][15]...[30]",
        27, 30, "[1]...[25][26][x][28][29][30]",
        30, 30, "[1]...[26][27][28][29][x]",
        3, 6, "[1][2][x][4][5][6]",
        4, 7, "[1][2][3][x][5][6][7]"];
for (var i=0; i<ts.length; i+=3) {
    var rr=v(ts[i], ts[i+1], 5);
    document.write(ts[i]+" of "+ts[i+1]+":  "+rr+" |Correct-> "+ts[i+2]+"<br>");
    ts[i+2]==rr ? document.write("<span style='color:green'>Check!</span>") : document.write("<span style='color:red'>Fail</span>");
    document.write("<br><br>");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby 1.9.1 — 114

```
for x,n,w in [[1,30,5],[2,30,5],[13,30,5],[27,30,5],[30,30,5],[3,6,5],[4,7,5]]

    puts (1..n).map{|i|i>[-w/2+x,n-w].min&&i<=[x+w/2,w].max||i==1||i==n ?"[#{i==x ?'x':i}]":'-'}.join.gsub(/-+/,'...')

end
```